# "ReferenceError: Markup is not defined" error in Node.Js Telegram Bot

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, referenceerror, telegraf.js

I want to make my telegram bot automatically reply user message with Image with description.I also want to add url inline button that redirect user to specific website.

Code:

```
const { Telegraf, Extra } = require("telegraf");
const bot = new Telegraf('my bot token');
bot.on('text', async (ctx) => {
  const message = `Test Message`;

  const imageUrl = 'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.com%2Fnews%2Fworld-us-canada-37493165&psig=AOvVaw0d_XITsiMbIX2n-18x9DGF&ust=1693310036962000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCMjv8sul_4ADFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE';
  const caption = message;
  const urlButton = Markup.inlineKeyboard([
    Markup.urlButton('Example Button', 'www.google.com'),
  ]);
});

bot.launch();
console.log('Bot Online!')
```

---

When user click the inline button, bot send error to console.

**Error:**

```
/home/runner/chatgpt-bot-telegram/index.js:38
  const urlButton = Markup.inlineKeyboard([
                    ^

ReferenceError: Markup is not defined
    at /home/runner/chatgpt-bot-telegram/index.js:38:21
    at /home/runner/chatgpt-bot-telegram/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:167:111
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async execute (/home/runner/chatgpt-bot-telegram/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:485:17)
    at async /home/runner/chatgpt-bot-telegram/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:486:21
    at async execute (/home/runner/chatgpt-bot-telegram/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:485:17)

Node.js v18.12.1
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
```

Comment: where do you define Markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `Markup` from the `telegraf` library.

```js
const { Telegraf, Extra, Markup } = require("telegraf");
```